# How to scroll automatically to a point in an image

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I'm writing an application for android in eclipse and my problem is:
I'm using ScrollView that contains an ImageView to contain an image.
In the image there are several locations that the user can search and when he choose
one location the location is mark as a red dot in the image. So far so good.
now when the searched location is somewhere at the bottom of the image then the user need to scroll to find it..
How can I make that the scrollView will scroll to the location automatically without the user's help?? What I need to do so that the searched location will be at the center of the phone's screen ??

Thanks for all your time and help !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use ScrollTo(x,y). The x,y are the position of the top left after the scroll, so you will need to adjust for the offset of your target location.

You could also enable smooth scrolling with setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true) and then do smoothScrollTo(x, y), which is like scrollTo(x, y), but scrolls smoothly instead of immediately.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView.ScrollTo(int x, int y) will be enough i guess . all you require is a relation between pixel and distance .